# Django TestCase do not pass anymore: wrong url

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I develop a DJango project and have develop few tests
One of these tests used to pass but do not anymore and I do not understand why

```
class IndexPageTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.pays = Pays.objects.create(pay_ide = 1,pay_nom = 'Côte d\'Ivoire',pay_abr = 'CIV')
        self.region = Region.objects.create(reg_ide = 1,pay = self.pays,reg_nom = 'Region 1',reg_abr = 'RE1')
        self.site = Site.objects.create(sit_ide = 1,reg=self.region,sit_typ = 'National',sit_nom = 'PA',sit_abr = 'PA')
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('user','user@user.com','password')
        self.profile = Profile.objects.create(user=self.user,site = self.site)

    def test_index_page(self):
        self.client.post('/registration/login/', {'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'})
        response = self.client.get(reverse('randomization:index'))
        print(response)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code,200)
```

print show it is not the good url (/accounts/login/?next=/randomization/ instead of /registration/login/):

`<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/accounts/login/?next=/randomization/">`

Answer (score 0):

The url you pass returns a 302 which means redirect.

Your URL is good but is just redirected. set your assertEquals status code to 302

Comment: but it used to run

Comment: when Slater user is log, he is redirect to the randomization:index url

Comment: how should I test user is correctly redirected? testing 302 does not seems good for me?